# What does it mean that "the action of $\mathbb{Z}$ on $M$ factors through the quotient $\mathbb{Z}/p^n \mathbb{Z}$"?

Tags: number-theory, commutative-algebra, modules, abelian-groups, group-actions

Let $M$ be a $\mathbb{Z}$-module, i.e. $\mathbb{Z}$ acts on $M$.

What does it mean that "the action of $\mathbb{Z}$ on $M$ factors through the quotient $\mathbb{Z}/p^n \mathbb{Z}$" ?

I want to understand it.

Suppose $\rho: \mathbb{Z} \times M \to M$ is defined by $\rho_z(m)=z\cdot m$ for all $z \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $m \in M$. Then "the action of $\mathbb{Z}$ on $M$ factors through the quotient $\mathbb{Z}/p^n \mathbb{Z}$" implies something like

[image]

where $\rho_1(z,m)=(z~\pmod{p^n},m)$ and $\rho_2(z~\pmod
{p^n},m)=z\cdot m$.

But still I don't have the motivation and clear understanding of what does mean by "the action of $\mathbb{Z}$ on $M$ factors through the quotient $\mathbb{Z}/p^n \mathbb{Z}$" ?

Any discussion is appreciated.

Comment: That $p^n.m=0$ for all $m\in M$ so $z.m=(z+p^n k).m$ ie. we can think to $z$ as belonging to $\Bbb{Z/p^nZ}$.

Comment: @reuns, thanks. Since we can think $z \in \mathbb{Z}$ belonging to $\mathbb{Z}/p^n \mathbb{Z}$, can we say $M=\mathbb{Z} \cdot m$ for some $m \in M$ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The group action can equivalently be described as a group homomorphism
$$\rho':\ \Bbb{Z}\ \longrightarrow\ \operatorname{End}(M).$$
That the action factors over $\Bbb{Z}/p^n\Bbb{Z}$ simply means that this homomorphism factors over $\Bbb{Z}/p^n\Bbb{Z}$.
That is to say $p^n\Bbb{Z}$ is contained in the kernel of $\rho'$, or equivalently  $p^n\cdot m=0$ for all $m\in M$.

Comment: Does it means $\varphi$ factors into product of two homomorphisms when restricted on $\mathbb{Z}/p^n \mathbb{Z}$ ?

Comment: @Mathlearner That is not what it means for a homomorphism to factor. It means that $\rho'$ is the composition of two group homomorphisms; one is the canonical projection from $\Bbb{Z}$ to $\Bbb{Z}/p^n\Bbb{Z}$, the other is the induced map from $\Bbb{Z}/p^n\Bbb{Z}$ to $\operatorname{End}M$.

Comment: thanks. Just one question. In addition to the above situation assume, $M$ is a free $\mathbb{Z}/p^n \mathbb{Z}$-module of rank $1$ i.e., $M \cong \mathbb{Z}/p^n \mathbb{Z}$, can we get some $m \in M$ such that $\mathbb{Z} \cdot m=M$ ? i.e., Is $M$ principally generated as $\mathbb{Z}$-module ?